# How to insert records based on another table value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following three tables:

**Permission**

```
| PermissionId | PermissionName |
+--------------+----------------+
| 1            | A              |
| 2            | B              |
| 3            | C              |
| 100          | D              |
```

**Group**

```
| GroupId | GroupLevel | GroupName            |
+---------+------------+----------------------+
| 1       | 0          | System Administrator |
| 7       | 0          | Test Group 100       |
| 8       | 20         | Test Group 200       |
| 9       | 20         | test                 |
| 10      | 50         | TestGroup01          |
| 11      | 51         | TestUser02           |
| 12      | 52         | TestUser03           |
```

**GroupPermission**

```
| GroupPermissionId | FkGroupId | FkPermissionId |
+-------------------+-----------+----------------+
| 1                 | 1         | 1              |
| 2                 | 1         | 2              |
| 3                 | 1         | 3              |
| 4                 | 1         | 4              |
```

I need to insert records into `GroupPermission` table, if table `Group`, `GroupLevel` column have **0**
then I need to take its `GroupId` and need to insert values to `GroupPermission` table as that particular id and 100.

In order to above sample table records, I need to insert the following two records to `GroupPermission` table,

```
| FkGroupId | FkPermissionId |
+-----------+----------------+
| 1         | 100            |
| 7         | 100            |
```

How can I do it

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are trying to do here. Why permission 100? Where does that value come from? And of course you have the column named like it is a foreign key but there is no value of 100 in your Permission table. But aside from the problematic integrity issues this insert is pretty simple.

Comment: I don't get this. Only GroupId 1 and 7 has GroupLevel = 0. Why are there other id's in the GroupPermission table?

Comment: @SeanLange Sorry, I just add sample data here, In Permission have `PermissionId`  100. I updated the question

Comment: @jarlh Actually, In my application already have above data and based on GroupPermission table my application gives some permission to groups. So now I need to give a permission 100 to 0 level group also. therefore I need to insert that values to GroupPermission table (using post deployment script)

Comment: Yeah look at my answer. That is what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not very clear and I can only assume the value 100 is a static value and that you don't actually have foreign keys as the names of the columns imply. Also, you really should avoid reserved words like "Group" for object names. It makes things more difficult and confusing.

The simple version of your insert might look like this.

```
insert GroupPermission
(
    FkGroupId
    , FkPermissionId
)
select g.GroupId
    , 100
from [Group] g
where g.GroupLevel = 0
```

--EDIT--

Since you want to only insert those rows that don't already exist you can use NOT EXISTS like this.

```
select g.GroupId
    , 100
from [Group] g
where g.GroupLevel = 0
    AND NOT EXISTS
    (
        select *
        from GroupPermission gp
        where gp.FkGroupId = g.GroupId
            and g.FkPermissionId = 100
    )
```

Or you could use a left join like this.

```
select g.GroupId
    , 100
from [Group] g
left join GroupPermission gp on gp.FkGroupId = g.GroupId
            and gp.FkPermissionId = 100
where g.GroupLevel = 0
    and gp.FkGroupId is null
```

Comment: I updated the question, In Permission table have PermissionId = 100.

Comment: OK that doesn't change how the insert would work. It only deals with the referential integrity piece.

Comment: can I do the same functionality using a merge query? just ask for my knowledge :)

Comment: You could I suppose but MERGE is way over the top for something like this. If you might have already have some of these values in the GroupPermission table then a simple left join or not exists would be way simpler.

Comment: yeah I need to avoid run the above your query if `GroupPermission` table already have above data, thats why I asked the merge query. can I do it? if yes, can you please tell me how to write it :)

Comment: You don't want to use a merge for this. That is not the right tool for the job.

Comment: so then you suggest use left join to check value exists? I'm I correct? So then how to write it